# Pass value to function from <a> tag, not from button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider the following link and associated Javascript function:

```
<a class="someClass" href="#" onClick="someFunc('someVal'); return false;">Run someFunc</a>

function someFunc(val) {
    doSomething(val);
}
```

I would prefer to refactor the link and Javascript function to support some additional functionality (the link is actually in a `div` returned by AJAX):

```
<a class="someClass" href="#" someAttribute="someVal">Run someFunc</a>

$(".someClass").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // How to get value of someAttribute?
    doSomething(val);
});
```

How can I get the value of `someAttribute`? Thanks.

Comment: `someAttribute` is not a valid attribute, you can use `data-*` attributes and use the jQuery `data` method for retrieving the value. http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: Thank you undefined! Although the answers below both answer the question asked, you do address the underlying issue. Please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, may I ask you something? please accept one of those answers, although I recommend using `data-*` attributes, but actually those answer your question. thank-you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `attr()` method

```
$(".someClass").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // How to get value of someAttribute?
   alert( $(this).attr('someAttribute'));
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/buC8k/

API refrence:  http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 2):

The clicked element is `this`. You may use the [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function :

```
var someValue = $(this).attr('someAttribute');
```